# How to backup and restore mysql without mysqldump

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I couldn't chroot to the broken ubuntu server, may i know how can i backup and restore the mysql server without mysqldump? Could it be copy the directory and replace to the new server?

Comment: What does "chroot to broken ubuntu server mean"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not guaranteed to work but you may try, and I suppose that mysql is not running.

You can copy everything from mysql data folder `/var/lib/mysql` (this is the default location, check yours) and put it in the new location/server, check config to see datadir location matches, restart services and see if it works.

The configs are under `/etc/mysql`.

And of course not to forget the file and directory permissions.

Here are two useful links.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/how-do-i-move-the-mysql-data-directory

Comment: If the OP tries this, very important that the SQL server isn't running!

Comment: @ivanivan, yes you are right. I thought anyway the mysql or the server is not running and the op cant login. Otherwise mysqldump is the best option.